# SCSS: Use CSS attibute selectors with css variables

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I am writing a SCSS mixin that includes a CSS attribute selector.

I want the value of the attribute selector to be a variable.

For example

```
$variable: primary;
$selector: ".page";
#{$selector} [for="#{$variable}"];
```

This should produce: `.page [for=primary]`

I have tried the following

1. Escaping the variable: `[for="#{$variable}"]`

   This gives the error:

   > Functions can only contain variable declarations and control directives.)
2. Concatenation: `[for= + #{$variable} + ]`

   This gives the error:

   > Invalid CSS after "...elector} [for= ": expected interp_string, was "+ #{$variable...")
3. Concatenation with quotes: `"[for=" + $variable + "]"`

   This gives the error

   > Invalid CSS after "...ctor} "[for=" +": expected number or function, was " $variable...")

Comment: which version of SASS are you running? http://sassmeister.com/gist/6758deb8ef1fd1d920b5 here it works fine

Comment: `#{$selector} [for="#{$variable}"] {}` works in SASS v3.4, so voting to close.